# Prove of a residue being zero

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, analyticity, singularity

Im working on a question but I don't understand the final part:

"Let $f$ have an isolated singularity at $z_0$ ($f$ analytic in a punctured neighborhood of $z_0$). Show that the residue of the derivative $f'$ at $z_0$ is equal to zero."

The proof is as following:
Take the general form $f(z)= ...+a_{-2}(z-z_0)^{-2}+a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{-1}+a_0+a_{1}(z-z_0)^{1}+a_{2}(z-z_0)^{2}+ ...$
Then $f'(z)= ...-2a_{-2}(z-z_0)^{-3}-a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{-2}+a_{1}+2a_{2}(z-z_0)+ ...$
The latter one doesnt have a $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ term therefore the residue is zero.

I don't get the final part, why does not having a $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ term imply the residue is zero?

For computing a residue I use the formula (for a pole of order m at $z_0$): $Res(f;z_0)=\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}((z-z_0)^mf(z))$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a function $f$ has Laurent Series expansion $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

then residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is $a_{-1}$ where $a_{-1}$ is the coefficient of the term $(z-z_0)^{-1}$.

So, if there is no term $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in $f'$, the coefficient, say $a'_{-1}$, is $0$ therefore the residue is $0$.

Comment: I edited my answer, thank you for the correction.

Comment: That's amusing - you edited your answer so as to be the same as mine.

Comment: No, I just checked http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexResidue.html for more information. Please try not to slander before knowing what peoples' intention is. You are not the only one here that knows residue is equal to the coefficient  $a_{-1}$ so that I could steal your idea, I just made a mistake and corrected it according to your feedback and the link that I gave. There is no reason to charge.

Comment: I didn't say anything about your intent. It _is_ amusing that you posted a wrong answer, I pointed out the error, and then when you fixed it it became the same as mine.

Comment: May it be the situation that you found amusing because a person with average knowledge of complex analysis would have thought what you have written in your first answer and what I have written after I edited my answer. Many people's answer would be the same as your answer before your edit so when I found a source *before reading your answer*, I corrected my answer and it became the same as yours. It wasn't like I didn't know anything about Laurent Series so I don't understand what is *amusing* here.

Comment: Face it, the whole thing's amusing. Yes, a person with an average knowledge should know that the definition of the residue is $a_{-1}$. So why did you post the first answer, when you knew it was so much more trivial? (Heh, you say you checked mathworld for more information... never mind.)

Comment: The answer is simple, I tried to use something from owner of the question and I made a mistake while doing it by considering the formula that I incorrectly used was general. If you find someone's mistake amusing (because you are saying that *whole* thing is amusing), I don't have anything to say to you except hoping that you won't make any mistakes in your whole life.

Answer (score 3):

The *definition* of the residue is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion.

**Or**, if you *must* use the Residue Theorem: If $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ and $f$ is differentiable on $\gamma$ the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus shows that $$\int_\gamma f'(z)\,dx=f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a)).$$So we *always* have $\int_\gamma f'=0$ if $\gamma $ is a closed curve.